# Custom has_one based on column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

New to Rails, was wondering if its possible to model this relationship with ActiveRecords:

I have the following models (simplified):

```
User:
 - name
 - email
```

```
Client:
 - name
 - address
```

And then I have a model `attendee` that relates to both these tables but with a type column:

```
| id | join_type | join_id | 
|----|-----------|---------|
|  1 |    user   |    1    |
|  2 |   client  |    1    |
```

Is there a way to model that with active records using `has_one` relation?

Something like:

```
class Attendee < ApplicationRecord

    # OBVIOUSLY DOESNT WORK
    has_one :user, ->() { where(join_type: 'user') }, :class_name => 'User'
    has_one :client, ->() { where(join_type: 'client') }, :class_name => 'Client'

end
```

So it would generate the correct left joins and so?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but not this way. You want a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: It would be easier to help with more information. Are users/clients attending an Event object? Is this a many to many relationship? Does the Attendee table exist as a join table connecting users and clients to events? If so, @tadman is right, you need a polymorphic association. Specifically a many to many polymorphic association. You mentioned in a later comment that some of the table already exist and you have legacy data to preserve. This means you need carefully written up and down migrations. We could better help you write those if you provide more detail your question

Answer (score 3):

Create attendees table with this structure

```rb
class CreateAttendees < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :attendees do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.string :linked_object_type
      t.bigint :linked_object_id
    end

    # optinal
    add_index :attendees, %i[linked_object_type linked_object_id]
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/models/client_attendee.rb
class Attendee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :linked_object, polymorphic: true, foreign_type: :linked_object_type
end
```

Then you can access to user/client from Attendee instance like this

```rb
   attendee = Attendee.first
   linked_object = attendee.linked_object # Depends on linked object type it will return the relative model instance
```

If you want to access attendees from User/Customer, you can define them like this

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This model is used to store user data
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendees, as: :linked_object, linked_object_type: 'User' # You can scope it yourself, and define has_one depends on your design. 
end
```

Comment: Hey daxanhkun! Thanks for the answer, I think this is more what Im looking for.
However one issue: the table currently exists. Meaning the `linked_object_type` column already has values that are not necessary the class names of my other models. Is there a way for me to map it? Like, "if the column is `client` I want to use the `ClientUser` model. If the column is `user` I want to use the `SystemUser` model"...?

Comment: You can just use `t.references :linked_object, polymorphic: true`. You do not need to configure `linked_object_type: 'User'`.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin I don't think there is a way to do that. The way that ActiveRecord does type inference is by looking at the column and just straight up constantizing the value and from there it gets a table name. If you're working with a legacy database you're very likely going to have to adjust it to work with ActiveRecord if you want all of its features.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin the way `ActiveRecord` works to determine which Model class should be used is exactly what `max` mentioned. Therefore, I think you should run a script to perform data migrate to make it works for Rails. If you need the original value for other system. I suggest you to perform mapping at that layer if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you're falling victim to the classic confusion caused by the horrible naming of `has_one` and `belongs_to`.

`belongs_to` means *this* models table has a column referencing another table (or the same table). This is what you actually want.

`has_one` means *the other* side has a column referencing this table. Kind of like `has_many` but it generates different methods and has `LIMIT 1` tacked onto the query. It would have saved us so much greif if it was named `referenced_by`.

What I think you may be looking for is an indirect association through a join table with a polymorphic assocation.

```
class Client
  has_many :attendences
  has_many :meetings, 
    through: :attendences, 
    as: :attendee
end

class User
  has_many :attendences
  has_many :meetings, 
    through: :attendences,
    as: :attendee
end

# I took the liberty of making the naming less confusing
class Attendence
  belongs_to :meeting
  belongs_to :attendee, 
    polymorpic: true
end

# Just an example - this class could be whatever you want
class Meeting
  has_many :attendences
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendences
  has_many :users,     through: :attendences
  has_many :clients,   through: :attendences
end
```

The way this works is that the attendences table has both a attendee_id and attendee_type column. The later stores the class name of the associated item.

You can create both columns at once in a migration by passing the `polymorphic` option to `add_reference`:

```
class CreateAttendences < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :attendences do |t|
      t.references :attendee, null: false, polymorphic: true
      t.references :meeting, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If this is actually a good design is debatable as you cannot use a foreign key constraint to maintain referential integrity on the database level.

The same goal can be acheived by simply creating two join tables even through ActiveRecord can't really treat it as a single assocation from the `meetings` end.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to define a `UserAttendee` model and a `ClientAttendee` model, both inheriting from attendee (= Single Table Inheritance, STI). So attendee will need a `type` column, which will be automatically populated when the subclasses are created.

```rb
# app/models/client_attendee.rb
class ClientAttendee < Attendee
  has_one :client
end

# app/models/user_attendee.rb
class UserAttendee < Attendee
  has_one :user
end
```

You can still use the `Attendee` class as you like.
You show a `join_id` field in the attendees table, this is not required for a has_one relationship, only a belongs_to relationship. `User` and `Client` will have columns user_attendee_id and client_attendee_id.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_attendee
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_attendee
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Rails. I would like to propose a simpler solution this way:

```
class CreateAttendees < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :attendees do |t|
      t.timestamps
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :client_id
    end

    #add Indices and Foreign Keys as you wish

    #add_index...
    #add_foreign_key...
  end
end
```

This way you can use all the data integrity featues of your favourite database system and simplify your rails code as following:

```
class Attendee < ApplicationRecord

   belongs_to :user, optional: true
   belongs_to :client, optional: true

   #if you like you can add a getter method:
   def linked_object
     return user || client  
   end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :attendee        # or has_many - as your data model requires
  
  # You can even add some data integrity features in rails using this:
  # has_one :attendee, dependent: destroy
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :attendee
  #has_one :attendee, dependent: destroy
end
```

This way the code is much easier to read and to maintain. And you will be happy to not having Attendee-Records which point to nowhere.